# how to check if time is more than 30minute?

Tags: php

I have saved a time. I would like to check whether the saved time is 30 minutes greater than the current time. You can see in the code what I have done so far but it doesn't work.

I would need some help fixing that code.

```
$current = "08:05";
$to_check = date('h:i');

if($to_check > $current + strtotime('30 minute')){
    echo "greater";
}
else {
  echo "not greater";
}
```

Comment: look at the units your comparing

Answer (score 2):

First, your `$current` isn't the current time, `$to_check` is, so your variable names are misleading.

That being said, store your "08:05" as a Unix timestamp then see if the difference between the two is greater than 30 * 60.

Answer (score 2):

```php
$seconds = 1800; // 30 mins
$time1 = strtotime($db_time) + $seconds;
if(time() >= $time1)
   echo "Time's up!"
else
   echo "time has not expired";
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
<?php
$current = date('H:i');
$to_check = date('H:i', strtotime('+30 minutes')); 
$to_check = date('H:i', strtotime($record['date'])); //If value is from DB

if($to_check > $current){
    echo "greater";
}
else {
  echo "not greater";
}
```

Comment: I think `$to_check` is loaded from the database (or any form of persistence) not created with `date()`.

Comment: @FabriceKabongo Edited

Answer (score 0):

Save time using time function this would give you time in seconds from 1970 so for example current time is 1501137539 and after 30 minutes it would be (1501137539 + 30*60) so you would just need to check if difference b/w current time and stored time is greater that 30*60 then half an hour is over.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this snippet:**

```
function x_seconds($to_check = 'YYYY-mm-dd H:i:s') {
    $to_check = strtotime($to_check);
    $current = time() + 1800; //We add 1800 seconds because it equals to 30 minutes
    return ($current>=$to_check) ? true : false;
}
```

*Or go pro, and have a custom "seconds since", just because you can?*

```
function x_seconds($to_check = 'YYYY-mm-dd H:i:s', $seconds = 1800) {
    $to_check = strtotime($to_check);
    $current = time() + $seconds; //We add x seconds
    return ($current>=$to_check) ? true : false;
}
```

**Example usage:**

```
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2017-07-27 05:00');
if(x_seconds($date)):
    print "Is within 30 minutes.";
else:
    print "IS NOT within 30 minutes";
endif;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to solve the issue

```
$current = strtotime('12:00:00');
$to_check = strtotime(date('H:i:s'));   
$newtime =  round(( $to_check - $current ) /60 );

if($newtime > 30){    
    echo "greater";
}else {      
    echo "not greater";    
}
```